# Consulta para conteo de datos, usando median() SQL Oracle

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Esta consulta es para una gráfica, saco el count() de los registros que son mayores, iguales o menores a una cierta cantidad, pero el campo de Media, necesito que sea dinamico, es decir que cada que se realice la consulta realice, calcule la media de las cantidades totales de registros.

Anexo codigo.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DIFERENCIA_MINUTOS > MEDIA THEN 1 END) MENOR,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DIFERENCIA_MINUTOS = MEDIA THEN 1 END) IGUAL,
COUNT(CASE WHEN DIFERENCIA_MINUTOS < MEDIA THEN 1 END) MAYOR,
COUNT(1) TOTAL,
MEDIAN(DIFERENCIA_MINUTOS) MEDIA
FROM(
    SELECT
      (TRUNC(MOD((FECHA_1 - FECHA_2) * 24, 24))*60) + TRUNC(MOD((FECHA_1 - FECHA_2) * (60 * 24), 60)) DIFERENCIA_MINUTOS
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT
         A.CREATED FECHA_1,
         B.CREATED FECHA_2
         FROM TABLA_1 A
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT CREATED FROM TABLA_2) B ON B.ID = A.ID
         WHERE 1=1
     )
 )
```

Gracias.